# Springboot + Elastic Search : How to build a LIKE query with fuzziness?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

```
    NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchQuery("name", strFilterText).operator(Operator.AND)
            .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ONE)
            .prefixLength(1))
            .build();

    SearchHits<CustomCompletion> search = elasticsearchRestTemplate.search(searchQuery, CustomCompletion.class, IndexCoordinates.of("customcompletion_2-index"));
```

When strFilterText is passed as `try` then it returns proper result, but when passed as `tr` or 't', then it return zero result.

How to build a like query with fuziness?

Document inserted :

```
    String tryCatchBlock = "try{" +
            "\n\n\t\t}" +
            "catch(Exception objException){" +
            "\n\n\t\t}";
    String tryCatchFinallyBlock = "try{" +
            "\n\n\t\t}" +
            "catch(Exception objException){" +
            "\n\n\t\t}" +
            "finally{" +
            "\n\n\t\t}";
    String tryFinallyBlock = "try{" +
            "\n\n\t\t}" +
            "finally{" +
            "\n\n\t\t}";
    repository.save(new CustomCompletion(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), tryCatchBlock , "Try Catch Block"));
    repository.save(new CustomCompletion(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), tryCatchFinallyBlock , "Try Catch Finally Block"));
    repository.save(new CustomCompletion(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), tryFinallyBlock , "Try Finally Block"));
```

Comment: Can you show us the document which you are expecting to be matched?

Comment: Its a normal try catch block.

Comment: @Gibbs Pasted the document which I am trying to insert.

Comment: What is the mapping for that field?

Comment: Its `name` only. Which is the 2nd element in the constructor.